# Visual Studio Code: Execute Test scripts?

Tags: unit-testing, typescript, visual-studio-code, execution

I am following the [Redux Tutorial](https://egghead.io/lessons/javascript-redux-writing-a-counter-reducer-with-tests) and try to implement it using TypeScript in Visual Studio Code. The tutorial makes use of the [Expect](https://github.com/mjackson/expect) library.

My question is: is there any chance I can execute the Expect-Tests (written in a `*.ts` file) directly from VisualStudio Code, or do I absolutely **have** to create a HTML page and run it in the browser? The latter seems extremely inconvenient. Please note that in this case, the file to run is a TypeScript file, so [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33850390/3094906) unfortunately does not work, because node can't deal with TypeScript files directly.

Answer (score 0):

It's not necessary to run TypeScript directly in node, you can compile your `*.ts` files into JavaScript `*.js` and run them.

You can play with a [sample project](https://github.com/zlumer/typescript-node-basic) to get the hang of it.

Basically, these are the steps to run your tests:

1. Compile your code from TypeScript to JavaScript.
2. Compile your tests from TypeScript to JavaScript.
3. Run tests in testing library of your choice (e.g. [`mocha`](https://mochajs.org/)).