# Struggling with code runner install for vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code

I installed code runner and tried to run console.log("hello") but I keep getting the following error.

```
bash: node: command not found
```

I went into the settings and set up the JavaScript like this:

[image]

Still no luck

is there a file I need in my working directory?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Run JavaScript in Visual Studio Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31778413/run-javascript-in-visual-studio-code)

Answer (score 0):

Installing nodeJS was required and problem solved. I didn't see it mentioned in the extension instructions.