# Running JS on VSCode

Tags: javascript

I tried running a simple javascript program

```
console.log('Hi');
```

However, when I try to run it - it gives me an error in the output:

```
/bin/sh: node: command not found
```

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Does this help you ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31778413/run-javascript-in-visual-studio-code

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Run JavaScript in Visual Studio Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31778413/run-javascript-in-visual-studio-code)

Answer (score 1):

Install [Node](https://nodejs.org/en/) (or, if it is already installed, make sure it is on your `PATH`).