# Can't seem to run selective chunk of Javascript code in VS code

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

So I am new to Javascript and trying to learn on VS Code. I can't seem to find a functionality to execute only a selected block of code. Every time I click F5 or (or Ctrl + F5), it runs the entire file.

Is it possible or do I need to install something extra to do this?

Comment: I think you should use [Quokka.js](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=WallabyJs.quokka-vscode)

Comment: Or take a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31778413/run-javascript-in-visual-studio-code