# Running Javascript in visual studio code

Tags: javascript, json

I started learning coding in javascript. Wanted to practise my skills using visual studio code but **I cannot run the code** (to test if it works). Ive spent many hours browsing google to find the setting, but so far I got to this jsconfig.json thing, placed it in my folder where other .js files are, but the .js file with my practice code still doesnt run. I right click in the field with javascript code, press run the code and it still doesnt run. I guess I am still missing something.
Would you be so kind to please advice me step by step what to do?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Rjxi.png)

Comment: Have you installed node.js and have you set it up in the user's path variable? The exception clearly says ```node: command not found```

Comment: Seems, you don't have a valid nodejs installation

Comment: You should read [ask]. In particular the section starting "DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc. -"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Run JavaScript in Visual Studio Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31778413/run-javascript-in-visual-studio-code)

Comment: @Alena : Welcome to stackoverflow. Kindly follow the advice of MR Quentin. Also, try node test1.js . GOD BLESS

Comment: @ To help you further since you are just starting... Go through this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VqCgcpAypFQ&feature=emb_logo Hope this helps :)

Comment: thank you all. @mohammad how do I install Node and activate it? I did checked the extensions panel. Or is this a separate programme? Once again thank you very much all.

Comment: Mr @quentin, apologies, I will not do that from now on.

Comment: @Imran - thank you too...I did see this advice, but it wasn't helpful to my issue unfortunately. So now, I should just activate the node? and in what way?

Comment: Hey Alena :) I would like to help you :) Let me know what you are trying to do !

Comment: I will help you step by step !!!  Don't worry :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227121/discussion-between-imran-rafiq-rather-and-alena).