# I can't see the output in Visual Studio Code-JavaScript

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

Does someone know why I can't see the output of `console.log` in Visual Studio Code?

[image]

I install the JavaScript and the runner but I still can not see anything.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Run JavaScript in Visual Studio Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31778413/run-javascript-in-visual-studio-code)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

maybe you didn't save it before run. try `ctrl + s` before you run the code;

[image]

Comment: Yes, this was, it works if I first use CRTL + S THANK YOU SO MUCH!