# How to show the value of an environment variable?

Tags: visual-studio-code

How can I easily display the value of Visual Studio Code's environment variabls like `${cwdFolder}` or `${workspaceFolder}`? (preferrably using the *command line*).

Comment: See https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_32#_variable-support-in-send-sequence-command and especially https://stackoverflow.com/a/55113523/836330

Comment: And `${env:PROGRAMFILES}` for environment variables.