# Vscode Debug Streamlining: How To HotKey Current File To Run in Visual Studio Code Terminal?

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-code

I'm new to Vscode.  In the old IDE I could hit a hotkey and the current file with window focus would execute in a terminal window.

I can't seem to replicate in Vscode?

CTR+F5, doesn't give me a terminal window.  Selecting "Run Without Debugging" from the run menu drop down doesn't seem to do anything either.

Right now I'm having to open a terminal window, save the script, and then run it in terminal seperately.

Surely there is an automated way to save, then run the script right in Vscode, and show me the terminal output?

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: @Mark Bash, Elixir right now.

Comment: Here is something which uses the `sendSequence` command to run the current file `${file}` in a node environment:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/55113523/836330.  I don't know anything about elixir bt maybe you can modify that to run an elixir file.